# In the Google Workspace Admin SDK userUsageReport API, is the specified date affected by any time zone?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api

We specify the "date" in the userUsageReport as shown in the reference below.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/userUsageReport/get

It is written as follows on the reference, but I'm not sure what it means.

> "We recommend you use your account's time zone for this."

I'm curious about the relationship between the specified date and the timezone.
Will it behave like one of the following? Does anyone know?

A. Data is acquired according to the time zone of the user account used for authentication when executing the API.

B. Data is retrieved according to the time zone of each user account specified in the API "userKey or all"

C. Data is retrieved according to uniform UTC or a specific time zone

Answer (score 0):

I believe option 'A' on your question is the correct one based on this [article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4579579) where it states:

> Date and time of the event (displayed in your browser's default time
> zone)

Every date/time that is logged into the user reports of the Admin Console will be automatically translated into your local time (e.g, the date and time shown in the 'Date' column of the results in the Admin console UI is the local time of the admin generating the report.)